# A selection-rectangle (drawn by mouse on canvas) does not recognize rectangles, which are inside that selection-rectangle (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, selection, rectangles

I am now really desperate. I just can't get any further and in principle it shouldn't be that difficult. I tried solving it the last 2 weeks.
The following task/problem:
I have a canvas in my C# WPF project called “MarkPointsMap”, on which there are different kind of mark points (3 different kind of rectangles with different colors). One MarkPointsMap can contain round about 3000-4000 different MarkPoints (Children of that canvas) all over across the MarkPointsMap.
The positions of that MarkPoints are loaded from a .tab-file, which is converted into a list called “MarkPoints” and added as Children on the “MarkPointsMap” canvas after loading the respective .tab-file.

This a screenshot of the MarkPointsMap:
[image: This a screenshot of the MarkPointsMap:]

There are e.g. mostly small rectangles (the green ones), a few middle rectangles (the yellow ones) and two big rectangles (the red ones). Mulitple markpoints should be selected with a selection-rectangle. In my project I can already draw the selection rectangle, but the “if this.selectRect.Contains(MarkPointsMap.Children)” (see below) part does not work.

The selection-rectangle looks as follows:

[image: The selection-rectangle looks as follows:]

The following method “drawMarkPoints”, which is called after loading the .tab file in the program, draws the markpoints on the canvas “MarkPointsMap”:

```
public void drawMarkPoints()
    {
        MarkPointsMap.Children.Clear();

        foreach (MarkPoint markpoint in this.Marks.markpoints)
        {
            if (markpoint.type.relevant)
            {
                Rectangle markpointArea = new Rectangle();
                markpointArea.Tag = markpoint;
                //!!
                SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
                mySolidColorBrush.Color = markpoint.fillColor;
                markpointArea.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
                markpointArea.StrokeThickness = 0.2;
                markpointArea.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

                markpointArea.Width = markpoint.symbol.Width;
                markpointArea.Height = markpoint.symbol.Height;
                //set the markpoints in canvas 
                Canvas.SetLeft(markpointArea, getCanvasCoordinates(markpoint.center).X - 0.5 * markpoint.symbol.Width); 
                Canvas.SetTop(markpointArea, getCanvasCoordinates(markpoint.center).Y - 0.5 * markpoint.symbol.Height);

                MarkPointsMap.Children.Add(markpointArea);
          
            }
        }
    }
```

The selection-rectangle is drawn in the canvas “MarkPointsMap” with the three Mouse-Events (MarkPointsMap_MouseDown, MarkPointsMap_MouseMove, MarkPointsMap_MouseUp):

```
public Rect itemRect;
public Rect selectRect;
private point anchorPoint; 
private Rectangle manualDragRect = new Rectangle(); 

private void MarkPointsMap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            isLeftMouseButtonDownOnWindow = true;
            anchorPoint = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(MarkPointsMap);
            MarkPointsMap.CaptureMouse();
            e.Handled = true;
            manualDragRect = new Rectangle
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Red,
                StrokeThickness = 2
            };
            MarkPointsMap.Children.Add(manualDragRect); 
        }       
    }

private void MarkPointsMap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!MarkPointsMap.IsMouseCaptured)
            return;

        Point location = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(MarkPointsMap);
        double minX = Math.Min(location.X, anchorPoint.X);
        double minY = Math.Min(location.Y, anchorPoint.Y);
        double maxX = Math.Max(location.X, anchorPoint.X);
        double maxY = Math.Max(location.Y, anchorPoint.Y);

        Canvas.SetTop(manualDragRect, minY);
        Canvas.SetLeft(manualDragRect, minX);

        double height = maxY - minY;
        double width = maxX - minX;

        manualDragRect.Height = Math.Abs(height);
        manualDragRect.Width = Math.Abs(width);
        Point xy_2 = new Point((Canvas.GetLeft(manualDragRect) + 0.5 * width), (Canvas.GetTop(manualDragRect) + 0.5 * height));
        this.selectRect = new Rect(xy_2.X, xy_2.Y, width, height);
    }


private void MarkPointsMap _MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MarkPointsMap.ReleaseMouseCapture();

        foreach (MarkPoint markpoint in this.Marks.markpoints) 
        {
            Rect itemRect = new Rect(markpoint.center.X, markpoint.center.Y, markpoint.symbol.Width, markpoint.symbol.Height);
            if (selectRect.Contains(itemRect))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Test!"); // it does not reach this code, if I circle several markpoints with the red selection-rectangle called “selectRect”
                
            }

        }
    }
```

Why doesn’t this work? I guess it has to do with the converting from rectangle (System.Windows.Shapes using derictive) to struct Rect : IFormattable.
The “if (selectRect.Contains(itemRect)”, which is not reached should in perspective color all mark points, which are inside the selection-rectangle in red, then compute the Point (x-Coordinate, y-Coordinate) of the middle-point of the selection-rectangle and add this middle point back to the original .tab-file.
Any ideas or hints, how I could continue? Thanks in advance.
Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your calculations are wrong. You are offsetting the `selectRect`. You are centering it relative to the rendered `manualDragRect`. This way you are testing a totally different area than the one you have defined by the rendered selection bounds.

Additionally, you are capturing the mouse on the `Canvas` but release the capture on some different control. It should be released on the `MarkPointsMap` too. Also be careful with marking mouse events as handled. If the input handling is not part of a custom control, you should generally avoid it.

You should consider to use an `ItemsControl` with a `Canvas` as panel. You can then move the drawing to the markup and define a `DataTemplate` for the `MarkPoint` data.

I recommend to use the original `Rect` returned from the `manualDragRect` shape. This means you should remove the `selectRect` field and related computations:

```cs
private void MarkPointsMap_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  MarkPointsMap.ReleaseMouseCapture();

  foreach (MarkPoint markpoint in this.Marks.markpoints)
  {
    Rect itemRect = new Rect(markpoint.center.X, markpoint.center.Y, markpoint.symbol.Width, markpoint.symbol.Height);

    Rect selectionBounds = manualDragRect.RenderedGeometry.Bounds;
    selectionBounds.Offset(Canvas.GetLeft(manualDragRect), Canvas.GetTop(manualDragRect));
    if (selectionBounds.Contains(itemRect))
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Test!");
    }

    // TODO::Calculate center of selectionBounds
    Point selectionBoundsCenter = ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply and input. In the real project the ReleaseMouseCapture(); is applied on the correct control. I forgot to rename the real name of the canvas to the edited name for stackoverflow. For this stackoverflow post I renamed the whole variable and control names, so that the real project is still anonymous. I changed it now in my original Post. I tried your code, but I still have the same weird behavior of the selection-rectangle.

Comment: I really wonder where and why you struggle. This is really a simple problem. I have updated my answer to give you a small and simple but full working example. It also shows you how to utilize the ItemsControl as Canvas host and DataTemplates to separate your calculations/data from the rendering. This should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: the problem was a scaling problem. The width of the MarkPointsCanvas was another as the width of the sheet of paper (the .tab-file, which is imported) and on which the marekpoints are drawn. With the correct scaling it now works. And also with your code.

Comment: Fine. So can I delete the example UserControl?

Comment: The problem with your posted code is that it doesn't show any scaling. It is also not mentioned in the question.

Comment: yes, never mind. You answered my post as far as it could be answered. I marked it as the answer. I can also delete my original post if it is better for the clarity of the stackoverflow platform.

Comment: Of course, I can not upload the whole project here, because it should stay anonymous. The problem was, that I had to continue the C# WPF project from a coworker. I thought that I was missing a basic concept concerning Selection-Rectangle in my knowledge. But the main problem, was that the selection rectangle could not catch the markpoints because the coordination-system-scaling of the markpoints was a whole different as the canvas and the selection-rectangle. I recognized it with debugging. My coworker was not aware of it anymore because he programmed it 2 years ago.

Comment: I see. We all have been through this. This can really spoil the day, especially when the author is no longer with your company. The moments we value any kind of documentation. I will then remove the latest example to keep the answer clean. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is unfortunately in need of improvement at our company. Thank you! :)